# How to access double arrow anchors to change colours

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the following figure:

```
\documentclass[margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

%
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \tikzset{
        line/.style = {draw},
        box/.style={arrow box, fill=#1},
    }
    \node[coordinate] (a) at (-10,-13) {};
    \node[coordinate] (b) at (-10,5) {};
    \node[coordinate] (c) at (9, 5) {};
    \node[coordinate] (d) at (9, -13) {};
    \draw[brown, line width=2pt, rotate=0, ] (a.center) -- (b.center) -- (c.center) -- (d.center) -- cycle;

    \draw[color= blue!30, line width=1pt, fill=blue!30] plot[domain=0:350, smooth cycle] (\x:2+rnd*0.5 and 3+rnd*0.5) node[] (cloud_A){};
    \node[color=black] at (3,0) (A){\Huge{A}}; 
    \draw[color= green!30, line width=1pt, fill=green!30, yshift=-8cm] plot[domain=0:350, smooth cycle] (\x:2+rnd*0.5 and 3+rnd*0.5) node[] (cloud_C){};
    \node[ color=black] at (3,-8) (B){\Huge{B}}; 
    \draw[color= red!30, line width=0pt, fill=red!30, yshift=-4cm, fill opacity=0.5] plot[domain=0:350, smooth cycle] (\x:2+rnd*0.5 and 3+rnd*0.5) node[] (cloud_B){};
    \node[color=black] at (3,-4) (C){\Huge{C}};
    \node (m) [] at ($(a)!0.5!(b)$) {};
    \node[rectangle, draw=black, fill=red!70!blue!70, text=white, left of=m, minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm] (R) [rotate=90]{\huge{Reader}};
    \node[circle,draw=black, thick] at ($(b)+(1,-1)$) (ANT1){\Huge{$1$}};
    \node[circle,draw=black, thick] at ($(a)+(1,1)$) (ANT2){\Huge{$2$}};
    \path [line,  line width=0.75mm] (R) |- (ANT1);
    \path [line, line width=0.75mm] (R) |- (ANT2);
    \node[rectangle, draw=black, fill=gray, minimum height=0.5cm,minimum width=2.5cm, rotate=45] at ($(ANT1)+(1,-1)$)  (PATCH1){};
    \node[rectangle, draw=black, fill=gray, minimum height=0.5cm,minimum width=2.5cm, rotate=-45] at ($(ANT2)+(1,1)$)  (PATCH2){};

    \node[minimum size=2cm, box=blue!50!green, arrow box arrows={west:3cm}, text=white] at (12,-4) (BATCH){\huge{Batch}};

    \node[] at ($(BATCH) + (0,-1.5)$) (TAG){\LARGE{N}};

    \node [minimum height=4.75cm, double arrow head extend=.4cm, fill=red!60, double arrow, draw=none, rotate=-45] at ($(PATCH1)+(3,-1.7)$) (ArrowP1){\huge{Policy $\alpha$}};
    \node [minimum height=4.75cm, double arrow head extend=.4cm, fill=blue!75, double arrow, draw=none, rotate=45, text=white] at ($(PATCH2)+(3,1.7)$) (ArrowP2){\huge{Policy $\beta$}};
    \node [minimum height=4.75cm, double arrow head extend=.4cm, fill=yellow!50, double arrow, draw=none, rotate=-45, ] at ($(ArrowP1)+(-1.25,-1.25)$) (ArrowP3a){\huge{Policy $\gamma$ ($50\%$)}};

    \node [minimum height=4.75cm, double arrow head extend=.4cm, fill=yellow!50, double arrow, draw=none, rotate=45, ] at ($(ArrowP2)+(-1.25,1.25)$) (ArrowP3b){\huge{Policy $\gamma$ ($50\%$)}};

    \node[coordinate] (disp) at (8,-4) {};
    \path[>={Triangle[width=3.6mm,length=2.mm]},->,line width=1.0mm, color=blue!50!green] (disp) edge [out=180, in=0] (A);
    \path[>={Triangle[width=3.6mm,length=2.mm]},->,line width=1.0mm, color=blue!50!green] (disp) edge [out=180, in=0] (C);
    \path[>={Triangle[width=3.6mm,length=2.mm]},->,line width=1.0mm, color=blue!50!green] (disp) edge [out=180, in=0] (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like to vary the colors of some of the point lines of the double arrow in yellow like this.

[image]

with the left and right lines of the arrow have different colours.

In the pgfmanual the double arrow anchor is named (Page.813):

[image]

I would like to change the color of the lines between `s.before tip 2` and s.after tip 2` for example, and, the same with the other side of the arrow, tip 1.

Comment: You can't change color only a part of border. This you can do by overdrawing desired part of `double arrow` shape  with `draw[<selected color> (s.after tip 2) -- (s.tip2) -- (s.before tip2); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add these colored lines to the definition of the respective arrow. This works with the `append after command` key as in

```
    double colored arrow/.style 2 args={double arrow,
    append after command={
    (\tikzlastnode.tip 1) edge[#1,line cap=rect] (\tikzlastnode.before tip 1)
    (\tikzlastnode.tip 1) edge[#1,line cap=rect] (\tikzlastnode.after tip 1)
    (\tikzlastnode.tip 2) edge[#2,line cap=rect] (\tikzlastnode.before tip 2)
    (\tikzlastnode.tip 2) edge[#2,line cap=rect] (\tikzlastnode.after tip 2)
    }}
```

Here is how one can then use the style.

```
\documentclass[margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

%
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \tikzset{
        line/.style = {draw},
        box/.style={arrow box, fill=#1},
        double colored arrow/.style 2 args={double arrow,
        append after command={
        (\tikzlastnode.tip 1) edge[#1,line cap=rect] (\tikzlastnode.before tip 1)
        (\tikzlastnode.tip 1) edge[#1,line cap=rect] (\tikzlastnode.after tip 1)
        (\tikzlastnode.tip 2) edge[#2,line cap=rect] (\tikzlastnode.before tip 2)
        (\tikzlastnode.tip 2) edge[#2,line cap=rect] (\tikzlastnode.after tip 2)
        }}
    }
    \node[coordinate] (a) at (-10,-13) {};
    \node[coordinate] (b) at (-10,5) {};
    \node[coordinate] (c) at (9, 5) {};
    \node[coordinate] (d) at (9, -13) {};
    \draw[brown, line width=2pt, rotate=0, ] (a.center) -- (b.center) -- (c.center) -- (d.center) -- cycle;

    \draw[color= blue!30, line width=1pt, fill=blue!30] plot[domain=0:350, smooth cycle] (\x:2+rnd*0.5 and 3+rnd*0.5) node[] (cloud_A){};
    \node[color=black] at (3,0) (A){\Huge{A}}; 
    \draw[color= green!30, line width=1pt, fill=green!30, yshift=-8cm] plot[domain=0:350, smooth cycle] (\x:2+rnd*0.5 and 3+rnd*0.5) node[] (cloud_C){};
    \node[ color=black] at (3,-8) (B){\Huge{B}}; 
    \draw[color= red!30, line width=0pt, fill=red!30, yshift=-4cm, fill opacity=0.5] plot[domain=0:350, smooth cycle] (\x:2+rnd*0.5 and 3+rnd*0.5) node[] (cloud_B){};
    \node[color=black] at (3,-4) (C){\Huge{C}};
    \node (m) [] at ($(a)!0.5!(b)$) {};
    \node[rectangle, draw=black, fill=red!70!blue!70, text=white, left of=m, minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm] (R) [rotate=90]{\huge{Reader}};
    \node[circle,draw=black, thick] at ($(b)+(1,-1)$) (ANT1){\Huge{$1$}};
    \node[circle,draw=black, thick] at ($(a)+(1,1)$) (ANT2){\Huge{$2$}};
    \path [line,  line width=0.75mm] (R) |- (ANT1);
    \path [line, line width=0.75mm] (R) |- (ANT2);
    \node[rectangle, draw=black, fill=gray, minimum height=0.5cm,minimum width=2.5cm, rotate=45] at ($(ANT1)+(1,-1)$)  (PATCH1){};
    \node[rectangle, draw=black, fill=gray, minimum height=0.5cm,minimum width=2.5cm, rotate=-45] at ($(ANT2)+(1,1)$)  (PATCH2){};

    \node[minimum size=2cm, box=blue!50!green, arrow box arrows={west:3cm}, text=white] at (12,-4) (BATCH){\huge{Batch}};

    \node[] at ($(BATCH) + (0,-1.5)$) (TAG){\LARGE{N}};

    \node [minimum height=4.75cm, double arrow head extend=.4cm, fill=red!60, double arrow, draw=none, rotate=-45] at ($(PATCH1)+(3,-1.7)$) (ArrowP1){\huge{Policy $\alpha$}};
    \node [minimum height=4.75cm, double arrow head extend=.4cm, fill=blue!75, double arrow, draw=none, rotate=45, text=white] at ($(PATCH2)+(3,1.7)$) (ArrowP2){\huge{Policy $\beta$}};
    \node [minimum height=4.75cm, double arrow head extend=.4cm, fill=yellow!50,
     double colored arrow={blue,thick}{red,thick}, draw=none, rotate=-45, ] at ($(ArrowP1)+(-1.25,-1.25)$) (ArrowP3a){\huge{Policy $\gamma$ ($50\%$)}};

    \node [minimum height=4.75cm, double arrow head extend=.4cm, 
    fill=yellow!50, double colored arrow={red,thick}{blue,thick}, draw=none, rotate=45] at ($(ArrowP2)+(-1.25,1.25)$) (ArrowP3b){\huge{Policy $\gamma$ ($50\%$)}};

    \node[coordinate] (disp) at (8,-4) {};
    \path[>={Triangle[width=3.6mm,length=2.mm]},->,line width=1.0mm, color=blue!50!green] (disp) edge [out=180, in=0] (A);
    \path[>={Triangle[width=3.6mm,length=2.mm]},->,line width=1.0mm, color=blue!50!green] (disp) edge [out=180, in=0] (C);
    \path[>={Triangle[width=3.6mm,length=2.mm]},->,line width=1.0mm, color=blue!50!green] (disp) edge [out=180, in=0] (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that you also can in principle use the node boundary path and partly color it with a dash pattern. In this case this is just not very convenient, but in principle it is possible.